# Parameter settings for neural networks based classification using Matlab

Tags: matlab, classification, pattern-recognition, neural-network

Recently, I am trying to using Matlab build-in neural networks toolbox to accomplish my classification problem. However, I have some questions about the parameter settings.

a. The number of neurons in the hidden layer:

The example on this page [Matlab neural networks classification example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/neural-network/code-examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/nnet/classify_wine_demo.html) shows a two-layer (i.e. one-hidden-layer and one-output-layer) feed forward neural networks. In this example, it uses 10 neurons in the hidden layer

```
net = patternnet(10);
```

My first question is how to define the best number of neurons for my classification problem? Should I use cross-validation method to get the best performed number of neurons using a training data set?

b. Is there a method to choose three-layer or more multi-layer neural networks?

c. There are many different training method we can use in the neural networks toolbox. A list can be found at [Training methods list](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/ug/train-and-apply-multilayer-neural-networks.html). The page mentioned that the fastest training function is generally 'trainlm'; however, generally speaking, which one will perform best? Or it totally depends on the data set I am using?

d. In each training method, there is a parameter called 'epochs', which is the training iteration for my understanding. For each training method, Matlab defined the maximum number of epochs to train. However, from the [example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/neural-network/code-examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/nnet/classify_wine_demo.html), it seems like 'epochs' is another parameter we can tune. Am I right? Or we just set the maximum number of epochs or leave it as default?

Any experience with Matlab neural networks toolbox is welcome and thanks very much for your reply. A.

Answer (score 0):

a. You can refer to [How to choose number of hidden layers and nodes in neural network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436209/how-to-choose-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-neural-network) and ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ3.html#A_hu
Surely you can do cross-validation to determine the parameter of best number of neurons. But it's not recommended as it's more suitable to use it in the stage of weights training of a certain network.

b. Refer to ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ3.html#A_hl
And for more layers of neural network, you can refer to [Deep Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning), which is very hot in recent years and gets state-of-the-art performances in many of the pattern recognition tasks.

c. It depends on your data.  trainlm performs better on function fitting (nonlinear regression) problems than on pattern recognition problems while training large networks and pattern recognition networks, trainscg and trainrp are good choices. Generally, Gradient Descent and Resilient Backpropagation is recommended. More detailed comparison can be found here: http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/nnet/ug/choose-a-multilayer-neural-network-training-function.html

d. Yes, you're right. We can tune the epochs parameter. Generally you can output the recognition results/accuracy at every epoch and you will see that it is promoting more and more slowly, and the more epochs the more computing time. You can make a compromise between the accuracy and computation time.

Answer (score 0):

For part **b** of your question:
You can use like this code:

```
net = patternnet([10 15 20]);
```

This script create a network with 3 hidden layer that first layer has 10 neurons, second layer has 15 neurons and 3th layer has 20 neurons.