# Python Back propagation hidden layer ratio

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to create a Back propagation network in Python. 
I have 14 input features and 1 output.  i am planning to use Multilayer neural network.

I am having the below question

1) What should be the i/p and hidden layer ratio?

I am little confused about the Hidden layer count.

Can any one help me.

Thanks,

**UPDATE :**

Input and my label

```
[[235, 2, -16.033171734306542, -828.0208534934904, 232965.81361002076, 2000.0, 11182359.053280996, 8565.232332709325, 4000.0, 0.019363246307941673, 1052153, 11313.47311827957, 105.79752842706958, 94],[10]],
[[-604, -6, 8.086235575302165, 380.8373042348658, 41190.53784866458, 2000.0, 1977145.8167358998, 420.30048579171057, 4000.0, 0.02123278230725872, 3436716, 36953.93548387097, 191.20880866382254, 94],[10]],
[[1825, 19, 14.022865897726179, -713.1319698367766, 97114.42605383566, 2000.0, 4661492.450584112, 1033.7486227812578, 4000.0, -0.019663774014977573, 3648687, 39233.1935483871, 197.01730672439965, 94],[10]],
[[-281, -2, -1.5372950205773066, 454.058413755312, 26895.611774858942, 2000.0, 1290989.3651932292, 765.2497914458995, 4000.0, -0.0033856767631790675, 5459685, 58706.290322580644, 241.00156704708152, 94],[10]],
[[1254, 13, 7.42946537169472, 236.81791472792207, 37351.8426913391, 2000.0, 1792888.4491842769, 923.863841127187, 4000.0, 0.03137205806507656, 5618776, 60416.94623655914, 244.48765360638856, 94],[10]],
[[55, 0, -6.799835826239174, -297.6057130887548, 7874.250847696101, 2000.0, 377964.04068941285, 66.64091494961357, 4000.0, 0.022848472079604405, 4150489, 44628.913978494624, 210.12886117302483, 94],[10]],
[[97, 1, 9.01187671470769, -55.32899089341877, 8218.299323445417, 2000.0, 394478.36752538, 127.66669905739745, 4000.0, -0.16287802414592073, 5331935, 57332.63440860215, 238.16530554628952, 94],[10]],
[[229, 2, 1.9250596458545362, -137.23162431944527, 16672.65593718128, 2000.0, 800287.4849847014, 130.52997477489504, 4000.0, -0.014027813599097374, 6905755, 74255.43010752689, 271.045159933551, 94],[10]],
[[107, 1, 6.470150940664045, 29.918507467688016, 26956.56324395225, 2000.0, 1293915.035709708, 165.12995290667556, 4000.0, 0.21625914820957587, 5269967, 56666.31182795699, 236.77727661962044, 94],[10]],
[[500, 5, 8.286114608469786, 122.0075128161886, 35446.863937609196, 2000.0, 1701449.4690052415, 253.11481415842877, 4000.0, 0.06791478997652628, 4669072, 50205.07526881721, 222.86986948307808, 94],[10]],
[[414, 4, 27.324467984592186, 485.55010485356297, 27500.260236682432, 2000.0, 1320012.4913607568, 214.55557670874316, 4000.0, 0.05627527975271053, 2489806, 26772.107526881722, 162.74918700976798, 94],[10]],
[[1044, 11, 4.238057309288552, -292.40132784218787, 8680.945668556162, 2000.0, 416685.3920906958, 475.7867593841577, 4000.0, -0.014493974225643315, 7271678, 78190.08602150538, 278.1335589168353, 94],[10]],
[[-528, -5, -10.252042152315722, 129.48476543188406, 20929.59991855366, 2000.0, 1004620.7960905757, 137.63411934477546, 4000.0, -0.07917566300653991, 7299292, 78487.01075268818, 278.6611608265341, 94],[10]]

    ]
```

Comment: @JanŽegklitz i have added my i/p

Comment: It's different for each task, but a rough guide to go on is for each layer to have 2/3 the number of nodes as the previous layer.

Comment: There is no definitive answer. Try eyeballing it with 0.5-0.75x the input size, test the network, evaluate, change layer size, reevaluate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so to reframe the problem w/r/t the practical objective: you just need to come with an integer value to represents the number of neurons that comprises the hidden layer so that:

- your solver (gradient descent, conjugate gradient, etc)
  converges during training; and
- the total error (eg, RMSE) falls below some threshold you've deemed acceptable to you.

almost certainly there are several values that will satisfy both of those criteria; what's more, there's no reason you can't manually adjust this value during training.

in fact, this is a common practice, usually referred to as *pruning*.

which nodes are candiates for pruning? Those with the  smallest weight values associated with them
(rember, weights apply to the connections between nodes not the nodes themselves). If they are
near zero then you know they have little influence on the result. (A commonly used technique to
visually examine these weights is a *Hinton Diagram* (there's a code snippet in the gallery of the matplotlib
homepage).

particularly given the latter, i recommend start by just choosing some integer which is just slightly larger than
your input layer. Why? Well clearly the size of those layers can't be equal or your network won't
have non-linearity, so that leaves either more neurons or less (relative to the input layer). As an initial guess
to interate on (ie, to adjust during iteration progress) the former is preferable because the excess
capacity will help your network converge, and that's what you want. Once it converges, then adjust downward the
number of nodes in the hidden layer and look at the effect on your total error from doing so.

in sum, in this case, begin with 16 or 18 neurons, observe the iteration progress and prune accordingly.

if you prefer a less empirical approach (ie, one with some numerical justification behind it and that attempts to determine an optimal network size *ex ante* rather than via iteration & pruning), please see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565868/what-is-the-criteria-for-choosing-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-hidden-la) (mine) to a similar question.