# How does nnfor library choose number of nodes in each layer in elm and mlp networks?

Tags: r, neural-network, forecasting

I use the `mlp` and `elm` functions from the `nnfor` library for forecasting non-stationary time series. Both of them give different number of nodes in input and hidden layers. I am interested in how they choose the number of nodes in each layer and it would be great to understand the generalization error change the way it works in that functions.

Comment: Hi Maksym  Welcome to stack overflow.  Do you mean elm instead of elp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of hidden nodes chosen by the `mlp` function depends on the value of the `hd.auto.type` parameter:

- "set" fixes hd=5.
- "valid" uses a 20% validation set (randomly) sampled to find the
  best number of hidden nodes.
- "cv" uses 5-fold cross-validation.
- "elm" uses ELM to estimate the number of hidden nodes (experimental).

The number of hidden nodes tried for the "valid", "cv" and "elm" parameter values range from 1 to `max(2, min(dim(X)[2] + 2, length(Y) - 2))`.  These hidden nodes are limited to a single layer.

The "cv" and "valid" approaches use the minimum of the mean square error to find the number of hidden nodes.

As far as I can tell from the `auto.hd.elm` function in the [source code](https://github.com/trnnick/nnfor/blob/master/R/mlp.R), the "elm" approach uses the median value of the number of significant model coefficients to choose the number of hidden nodes.  Hope that makes sense to you!

The `elm` function uses `min(100 - 60*(type=="step" | type=="lm"),max(4, length(Y) - 2 - as.numeric(direct)*length(X[1,])))` to determine the number of hidden nodes.  Where `type` is estimation used for output layer weights and `direct` is presence of direct input-output connections.

The number of input nodes depends on seasonality and lags.

Generalization error can be approximated using cross-validation.  To be clear, this cross-validation would have to be done separately from any validation used to find the number of hidden nodes.

The nnfor package author has an introductory blog post which may be worth checking: http://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2017/02/10/forecasting-time-series-with-neural-networks-in-r/

Comment: Thank you for your approach, is it possible to draw such plot like here.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10568938/10595361) I mean it is needed some values for it , do we get them after using that functions `mlp` or `elm`.

Comment: To produce something similar to the linked plots: 1) create separate test and train data sets, 2) train model with n hidden nodes, 3) produce predictions with forecast/predict function, new model and test data set, 4) calculate error (probably want mean square error) between predictions and test data set, 5) finally plot error as a function of n (number of hidden nodes).  Steps 2 to 4 would have to be repeated for each number of hidden nodes.  It's not possible to produce the linked plot with the nnfor package.

Comment: Understood, thank you . Could you answer one more question.. how does it choose that number of input nodes depending on seasonality and lags ?

Comment: it is written that **"Lags of y to use as inputs. If none provided then 1:frequency(y) is used. Use 0 for no univariate lags** but I my case I have frequency equals to 365, and it gives me number of 41 input nodes in mlp function and 100 in elm. Why it is so? O.o