# Designing the hidden layers of a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have classification problem, I have an input shape (16x16 image) and I need to classify that shape as the correct shape or not, so I have 256 (16*16) input neurons and one output neuron.

What about the middle? I'm not sure how many layers of hidden neurons are required, and how many neurons should be in each layer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345079/estimating-the-number-of-neurons-and-number-of-layers-of-an-artificial-neural-ne)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a formula based on the intuitive observations and empirical results in which, we can define the number of the hidden layer's neurons:

```
2*(N1 + N3) <= N2 <= (K*(N1 + N3) - N3) / (N1 + N3 + 1)
```

> N1: Number of the Input neurons,
>
> N2: Number of the Hidden neurons,
>
> N3: Number of the Output neurons,
>
> K: Number of the input samples.

You can calculate the number of the neurons in the hidden layer based on the empirical results in most JCR indexed papers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really tell because it varies a lot, but mostly depends on how much noise can be.

You need to by test yourself how many you need, but the number ranges between 1 and 256.